Visual studio code don't switch virtual environment in the terminal automatically
As I was said:visual studio code don't switch virtual environment in the terminal automatically
I have many projects and I want to vscode automatically switch venv in every project if venv is created. How I can do it? I switch "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true for user and workspace, but its not working. When I chosen the interpreter to venv/Scripts/python.exe and its working, but I need to the terminal automatically enter venv/Scripts/activate in the every project. I need it to install some libraries to venv, but not to global. vscode chose interpreter correctly, in the terminal is path of my project without venv prefix
I was tryed "python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal": true in the settings.json, but its not working for one of my workspace, but i want to it will working for all my projects
